# Model MLE finite values needed

Tags: r

I am trying to use mle to find the conditions of my model fitted to some data however I am getting the error  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'.
I am not really sure how to find where there are the non-finite values

```
sir.model2 = function(t, x, params){
  # extract the state variables
  S = x[1]
  I = x[2]
  R = x[3]
  # extract the parameters
 if(t<params['Time']){
  beta = params['beta.1']
  }else{
  beta = params['beta.2']
  }
  gamma = params['gamma']
  # compute the derivatives
  dSdt = -beta * S * I
  dIdt = beta * S * I - gamma * I
  dRdt = gamma * I
  # return the computed derivatives
  list(c(dSdt, dIdt, dRdt))
}

# define the negative log likelihood function
NLL2 = function(beta.1,beta.2,time, gamma, I.init){
  # specify the parameter values
  params = c(beta.1 = beta.1,beta.2=beta.2,Time=time, gamma = gamma)
  # specify the model's initial conditions
  xstart = c(S = 1-I.init, I = I.init, R = 0)
  # solve the differential equations
  out = ode(func = sir.model2, y = xstart, times = times, parms = params)
  out=as.data.frame(out)
  out$beta[out$time<params['Time']]<-params['beta.1']
  out$beta[out$time>=params['Time']]<-params['beta.2']
  # calculate the negative log likelihood
  -sum(dpois(data.edu$Cases, out$beta*out$S*out$I* N.edu, log=T))
}

m = mle(minuslogl = NLL2,
        method="L-BFGS-B",
        start = list(beta.1 = 1.5 * 1 / 7,beta.2 = 1.5 * 1 / 7,time=20, gamma = 1 / 7, I.init = 0.0001),
        lower = list(beta.1 = .1, beta.2 =.1,time=.1 gamma = 1e-3, I.init = 1e-3),
        upper = list(beta.1 = 5, beta.2 =5,time=107 gamma =5,  I.init = 1-1e-3)
        )
coef(m)
```

Comment: You should check the fidelity of your copy-paste operations. I'm getting an "unexpected symbol error" and that generally mean a missing comma or missing paren.

Comment: And sure enough: `time=.1 gamma = 1e-3,` is NOT legal R. However, now I get `could not find function "mle"`. So also learn to post `library` calls to load packages.

Comment: Needs to have the missing commas placed back in and the libraries that contain `mle` and `ode` specified in `library()` calls. Even after guessing that mle is in stats4 and that ode is in deSolve, I still getting error messages about missing parameters. Voting to close as needing further details.